# How to compute a definite integral of the form $\int_a^b f(x)g(x)dx$? Is there perhaps a trapezoidal sum formula for $f(x)*g(x)$?

Tags: definite-integrals

I need help with this to verify results that I obtained while running a program in Matlab which utilized its built in Trapezoidal Sum function to numerically compute an integral. So, here is an example that I went over which follows the form of $x[n] = \int_a^{b} f(x)g(x)dx$, what I tried, and what I know I'm supposed to get.

The following equations and setup were used below:

1. Trapezoidal Rule (as it is defined in Matlab): $\int_a^b f(x)dx \approx \frac{b-a}{2N} \sum^N_{n=1}(f(x_n) + f(x_{n+1}))$. Repurposed for our example, we sum over each $\omega$ instead of n. We can see it does not include $g(x)$
2. For our f(x) equivalent, we have $f(e^{j\omega}) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{n = +\infty}e^{j\omega_0 n}e^{-j\omega n} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{n = +\infty}e^{j(\omega_0-\omega)n} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{n = +\infty}2\pi\delta{(\omega-\omega_0-2\pi l)}$. This is commonly known as an impulse train and the sum is simply equal to $2\pi$ at $\omega = \omega_0 \pm 2\pi$ and we'll be integrating over an interval of $2\pi$ so this term shouldn't be an issue.
3. And our g(x) equivalent is $g(e^{jw}) = e^{j\omega}$ where again, we will be setting the value of n to some constant. This is a complex exponential and the fact that it is complex should not complicate anything.
4. This gives us the full form of our integral as: $\require{cancel} x[\cancel{n}\color{red}{i}]= \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{2\pi}X(e^{j\omega})e^{j\omega n}d\omega = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{2\pi}\sum_{l=-\infty}^{l = +\infty}2\pi\delta{(\omega-\omega_0-2\pi l)}e^{j\omega n}d\omega$
   $\color{red}{\textrm{where n is }n = [0,1] \textrm{ with }dn = 0.1\textrm{ and }\omega =\omega(n[i])}$
5. Lastly, we will be going over an interval of 11 terms also meaning there will be 11 $\omega$. It will be within the domain of integration of $[0,2\pi]$ and will have a $d\omega = \frac{2\pi}{N-1} = \frac{2\pi}{10}$ with the N-1 being due to using a finite scheme so we have N-1 deltas. Lastly, our $\omega_0$ term is $\omega_0 = \frac{2\pi}{N} = \frac{2\pi}{10} = \frac{\pi}{5}$ (which just so happens to be the same as our $d\omega$).

With all of this laid out, we start can start computing everything. The following are what I obtained for each term:

1. $f(e^{j\omega}) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{n = +\infty}e^{j\omega_0 n}e^{-j\omega n} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{n = +\infty}e^{j(\omega_0-\omega)n} = \sum_{l=-\infty}^{l = +\infty}2\pi\delta{(\omega-\omega_0-2\pi l)} = [0,2\pi,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]$

Note: $\require{cancel}\omega = [0,\frac{\pi}{5},\frac{2\pi}{5},\frac{3\pi}{5},\frac{4\pi}{5},\pi,\frac{6\pi}{5},\frac{7\pi}{5},\frac{8\pi}{5},\frac{9\pi}{5},2\pi]$

2. $\require{cancel}n = \cancel{1}\color{red}{n[1] = \frac{1}{10}}; g(e^{j\omega}) = e^{j\omega * \cancel{1}\color{red}{\frac{1}{10}}} = [1,e^{1j\frac{\pi}{\color{red}{50}}},e^{1j\frac{2\pi}{\color{red}{50}}},e^{1j\frac{3\pi}{\color{red}{50}}},e^{1j\frac{4\pi}{\color{red}{50}}},e^{1j\frac{5\pi}{\color{red}{50}}},e^{1j\frac{6\pi}{\color{red}{50}}},e^{1j\frac{7\pi}{\color{red}{50}}},e^{1j\frac{8\pi}{\color{red}{50}}},e^{1j\frac{9\pi}{\color{red}{50}}},e^{\frac{10\pi}{\color{red}{50}}}]$

Now we have these two arrays and we have to multiply them together in some way. So what I did next was I then plugged what are analogously our f(x) and g(x) functions into the Trapezoidal rule to get the following computation:

$\frac{b-a}{2N} = \frac{2\pi-0}{2(11-1)} = \frac{\pi}{10}$

$\require{cancel}x[1] = \frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{\pi}{10}\sum^N_{i=1}((f(e^{j\omega_i})*g(e^{j\omega_i})) + (f(e^{j\omega_{i+1}})*g(e^{j\omega_{i+1}})) = ((0 *1)+(2\pi *e^{1j\frac{\pi}{5}}))+((2\pi *e^{1j\frac{\pi}{\color{red}{50}}})+(0 *e^{1j\frac{2\pi}{\color{red}{50}}})) + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0= 4\pi e^{1j\frac{\pi}{\color{red}{50}}} \color{red}{*\frac{1}{20}}= \cancel{0.5083 + 0.3693j} \color{red}{0.6271 + 0.0395j}$

I decided to switch the summation index to "m" instead of "n" which I left reserved to x[n] which is just a subtle difference to help suit my version of the problem.

So basically, I took each term for f(x) and g(x) at their respective index and I multiplied them together. I know this is incorrect but I wanted to at least show my though process on this. The correct result which was obtained through Matlab is actually **0.62707 + 0.0394i** which likely used some conditional subroutine hidden in the code to compute the integral properly in the instance that the integrand is of the form $f(x) * g(x)$ but does not share *that* version of the formula with the user. Does anyone know what I was supposed to do instead to arrive to this result? Is there perhaps a modified formula for the Trapezoidal sum for this type of problem?

EDIT: As requested, I have provided the code below. It goes over the setup, building what are analgously f(x) and g(x) which I have commented for which is which, and the computation of the integral of f(x) * g(x) using Matlab's built in subroutine `trapz(dx,x)` which from the documentation uses the formula presented in what is listed as the first item in the list discussing the equations and setup I used.

Code used:

```
% Setup
    L = 5;len_n = 11; len_ninf = 101;
    n_inf = linspace(-L,L,len_ninf);
    omega = 2*pi .* n_inf;
    N = length(n);
    omega_o = 2*pi/((length(n_inf)-1)/10);
    l = -500:1:500; % some harmonic 

%build f(x) and g(x)
    x = exp(1j.*omega_o.*n_inf);           % g(x)
    impulsetrain = zeros(1,length(omega)); % f(x)
        for i = 1:length(omega)
            for j =1:length(l)
                if round(((round(omega(i),2)- round(omega_o,2)) -2*round(pi,2)*l(j))/1000,4)==0
                    impulsetrain(i) = 2*pi*1;
                end
            end
        end
    
% Compute integral from a to b of f(x) * g(x)$
    del_omega = (omega(length(omega))-omega(1))/(length(omega)-1);
    LeftBound = 0; RightBound = 2*pi + LeftBound;
    range = find(round(omega,2) == round(LeftBound,2)):find(round(omega,2) == round(RightBound,2));

    x_dift = zeros(1,length(n_inf(range))); % integral of f(x) * g(x)
    for i = 1:length(n_inf(range))
        x_dift(i) = 1/(2*pi) * trapz(omega(range),impulsetrain(range).*exp(1j*n_inf(range(i)).*omega(range)));
    end
```

x_dift is the object holding the values for the integral of what is analogously f(x) * g(x). Going to `x_dift(1)` will show the value which we are trying to obtain. The way in which I hand computed it I did not code as I feel I sufficiently showed the process of what I was doing with the equation and working that I typed out with x[1], however I could just as easily add it should someone ask.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have taken time to explain things in a detailed manner but, as Matlab programming is the issue, you should provide the code. As it is written, frankly, I don't see where the problem is. Btw : A little doubt about a common error : As you use complex $i$ and $j$, have you checked that you don't use $i$ or $j$ as loops indexes ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Alright then! I'll go ahead and provide the code in a new section at the end, should take an hour at the most. Should be done within an hour. I can add a few figures too to plot each object created too if you'd like for visualization sake, just let me know. And yes I believe I made sure to properly index everything in the loops but that could be correct. This was actually an offshoot of a different question I was having so who knows, maybe this will fix both problems if that was the problem.

Comment: If you have code that can numerically integrate $\int_a^bh(x)\,dx$ and want to run this on $h(x)=f(x)g(x)$ it is a no brainer that you write a helper function for $h$ that takes $f$ and $g$ as inputs and call your old integration code.

Comment: @KurtG. I think there is a misunderstanding. I don't have integration code written. I decided to instead replicate what I think the built in algorithm in matlab would have performed in a sample calculation for $f(x)g(x)$ (or $h(x)$ being the integrand to make it consistent with what you are saying) using Matlab's formula from the documentation. The result I obtained was incorrect, not because I made mistake in the coding, but because my methodology itself was wrong. That was part of the reason of showing a sample calculation since there is no room for coding error in that, just methodological

Comment: @KurtG. What I'd like to know is if you see a mistake in the methodology since it yielded an incorrect result. There seems to be a different methodology being performed in the case that I am performing $int_a^b f(x)g(x) dx$? I wrote it out in my formulation for x[1]. Is that the proper way to perform this computation by hand?

Answer (score 2):

Too long for a comment. As far as I gather you want to integrate $f(x)g(x)$ where
\begin{align}
f(e^{j\omega}) &= \sum_{n=-\infty}^{n = +\infty}e^{j\omega_0 n}e^{-j\omega n} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{n = +\infty}e^{j(\omega_0-\omega)n} = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{n = +\infty}2\pi\delta{(\omega-\omega_0-2\pi\color{red}{l})}\,,\\
g(e^{jw}) &= e^{j\omega n}\,.
\end{align}
Even if we fix that notation in the last formula I think it stays wrong:
\begin{align*}
f(\omega)&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}e^{j\,\omega n}=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\cos(\omega n)+j\,\sin(\omega n)\,.
\end{align*}
Since $\sin(-\omega n)=-\sin(\omega n)$ the $\sin$-terms all cancel. Since $\cos$ is even we get
\begin{align*}
f(\omega)&=1+2\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\cos(\omega n)\,.
\end{align*}
According to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/151979/949989)
that series does not look like it converges.

Regarding your numerical integration exercise: I strongly advice to test that code on functions that are less complicated and perhaps have integrals where the solution is known. Even if you have a delta function that you'd like to integrate how would you do that numerically? How would you even *implement* that delta function? Assume you approximate it with
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma}}\exp(-\frac{x^2}{2\sigma^2})
$$
how would you design your numerical integration when $\sigma$ is very small? Note that this function has a known integral from $-\infty$ to $+\infty\,.$

Comment: A couple of things. I noticed you colored the "l". To clear that up, that was the formulation as it was written in a textbook. The index variable changed to "l" when it was originally "n". So it should be an impulse at every $\omega = \omega_o \pm 2\pi l$. I apologize for the confusion that lifting it from the text has created. As for the integration variable, yes it's with respect to $\omega$. Please check the formula I have for $x[n]$ in the first numbered list for item 4.

Comment: As for your statement on the lack of necessity here, that may be the case, but I'm only doing this to diagnose a potential issue that may be a part of a larger problem by performing some hand calculations to see if some values match up. When they weren't it raised another question for what was going wrong. You can find the question [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4616666/issue-with-idtft-inverse-discrete-time-fourier-transform-of-a-periodic-impulse) for context if curious. It is getting a bit late so if you have anything to add, I will have to check it later. Sorry and thanks

Comment: Actually one last thing, thinking back on it, because the integral is only a single period of length $2\pi$ between a and b, you would be correct to write the impulse like the way you did since it only takes into account a single impulse at $\omega  = \omega_0$ and not elsewhere (i.e. $\omega \pm 2\pi$. That would indeed be correct what you said in your proposed answer.

Comment: It looks like you made some updates, but apparently stackexchange does not give updates to proposed answers. I am still rather new, so I missed them until now. Apologies for lack of communication. First I'd like to say that I found the problem. It was not an issue with the integration methodology, but a silly mistake in my code (as it always is with me). I was misinterpreting n. I have n on the range of 0 to 2pi at n = [0,1] with dn = 0.1. I was instead using the index itself as the value in my sample calculations. I have crossed out the mistakes and made the replacements in red.

Comment: Regarding the last statement, I was approaching things analytically (i.e. numerically) because I wanted to test the flexibility of this approach for my research. I incorporated impulses numerically by having an array of zeros and a non-zero at $\delta(0)$. The provided code to line 19 and then running `scatter(omega,impulsetrain); stem(omega,impulsetrain);` should show that we can make one numerically. From what it sounds like, this approach is improper for impulses, am I correct? It would explain why I couldn't get the correct result in the original problem I linked that this one stems from.

Comment: @ResearcherR "From what it sounds like, this approach is improper for impulses, am I correct?" To make a long story short: my answer is yes. The rest of your OP is still too long to read.

Comment: That's rather unfortunate. I managed to work out the solution in a continuous scheme by hand. Hopefully this issue is limited to impulses and works appropriately for other discrete time periodic signals.

Comment: Also the impulse allows it to avoid the convergence issue that you mentioned. Assuming that the interval of integration contains one impulse at $\omega_0 + 2\pi r$, then $x[n] = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{2\pi}(\sum\delta(\omega-\omega_0 - 2\pi l))(e^{j\omega_0*n})d\omega = \frac{1}{2\pi} (0+0+...+2\pi * 1 * e^{j(\omega_0+2\pi r) n}+0+0+...) = e^{j\omega_0 n}(cos(2\pi r n)+jsin(2\pi r n)) = e^{j\omega_0 n}$. Your formulation and reasoning were entirely correct in that the infinite sum of $g(e^{j\omega}$ does not converge, though thankfully $f(e^{j\omega})$ is the term being summed infinitely.